# Create crontab with python-crontab in Python?

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to add a line to my system user's crontab, from a Python script which uses the package python-crontab. My crontab file does not exist yet, and when I run this code, nothing happens (no errors, no results, no creation of crontab file):

```
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user=True)
# cron = CronTab(user='my_user') I tried this line too without any results

job = cron.new(command='python3 /opt/my_script.py')

job.minute.on(2)
job.hour.on(12)

True == job.is_valid()
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think getting user cron should be: user_cron = CronTab('user_name'), rest seems correct.

Comment: `True == job.is_valid()` does nothing. You should use `assert job.is_valid()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the cronjob, that's all that's missing:

```
#!/bin/python 

from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user=True)

job = cron.new(command='python3 /opt/my_script.py')
job.minute.on(2)
job.hour.on(12)

cron.write()
```

Comment: I have realized I had not read that part on the tutorial just before reading your post. Thank you of course.